# Allowing JS components to both work in browser commonJS env and default (as a window global)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, client-side, dependency-management, commonjs

I'm reading up on repackaging loads of javascript files as CommonJS components. 
However for various reasons (unit testing comes to mind) I'd like these components to also work in a default browser environment (i.e.: probably by attaching the components to `window` with some agreed upon namespacing, etc.)

To accomplish this, I've seen the following:

```
window.app = window.app || {};
var DetectStrategy = function(){
   ....
}
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = DetectStrategy;
}else{
    window.app.DetectStrategySimple = DetectStrategy;
}
```

This works ok, but breaks down if inside the module I'm doing a require for another module: `require` isn't available in a default browser environment.

```
window.app = window.app || {};
var DetectStrategy = function(){
   var relatedModule = require("./someOtherModule);
   ...
}
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = DetectStrategy;
}else{
    window.app.DetectStrategySimple = DetectStrategy;
}
```

It's completely logical that this fails, but imho it kind of defeats the purpose of trying to have a module work in both environments. After all, being able to call `require` (and it's related benefits of dependency management) is one of the main benefits of using CommonJS to start with.

So how would you solve this?

- being able to use a module on the clientside both in a COmmonJS and a default environment (for testing)
- make use of of dependency management (through `require` or whatever)

Comment: I don't understand what your aim is. If what you are looking for is a pure CommonJS style of module declaration, then RequireJS does not belong in your tags because while RequireJS has facilities to help *convert* modules written in the CommonJS style to AMD, at the end of the day the modules loaded by RequireJS are not CommonJS modules.

Comment: Agreed RequireJS doens't belong. Basically I want to do node-style requiring of modules using `require()` on the client-side as illustrated in the example. However I can't do this, since the modules may also be run (think unit tests) without `require()` being available. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yep, it makes sense. What I've done is write AMD-style modules that can run in Node and in the browser so the unit tests can be run in Node and the code can be used in a browser app, but I've not done the same with CommonJS-style modules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make JavaScript module compatible with both NodeJS and RequireJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263944/is-it-possible-to-make-javascript-module-compatible-with-both-nodejs-and-require)